# how to protect hard disk data from a live cd?

Tags: linux, livecd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Risk to native OS from Live CD?](https://superuser.com/questions/150607/risk-to-native-os-from-live-cd)

when booted from linux live cd, all partitions of hard disk become accessible without any restriction. How to block this?

Answer (score 1):

You should encrypt your filesystem and protect with password. Google `CryptofS`!

Comment: what about FAT32?

Comment: @Garry what about it?

Answer (score 0):

Some options include:

- Disabling the HDDs in the bios.
- Unplugging them.
- Making a custom live cd that has the behavior you want.
- Downloading an alternate live cd that has the behavior you want.
- Seeing if the live cd has some startup options allowing you to configure it how you want.

Comment: computer is mine and live cd may be used by someone unauthorised.

Comment: @Garry. I see, then Notinlist's encryption is the right solution.